After deleting an app in App Store Connect, how long after can a new app be created using the same name?
Since app names in App Store Connect must be unique, how long after deleting an app in App Store Connect can a new app be created using the same name? I've contacted Apple support about this and have gotten mixed answers depending on who I was speaking with. Therefore, from your personal experience, what have you seen?

As of this answer (2024), the name of the app will become available instantly after the app has been removed from the App Store and deleted from App Store Connect, which can be a matter of minutes. Contrary to the past, the same organization can use the deleted name as the name of a new app. The bundle ID, however, and perhaps the SKU, must be different.
